# Looking for tool to generate diagram from K8s Yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, diagram

I am looking for a tool that will present a microservices diagram from a YAML file or create a file that I can import into something like Visio.

Answer (score 1):

How about converting to JSON first with something like https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv

and then use [`json-to-plantuml`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-plantuml). You can test the output with http://plantuml.com/. I don't think there is a silver bullet so you might have to tweak the output to get what you want.